# add space between R code blocks and text in bookdown for html output

Tags: css, r, rstudio, knitr, bookdown

I am trying to add some space between text and code blocks in the HTML output of a book created with `bookdown`. I added the following to `p.caption` in the `style.css` file, and it adds space after figure captions.

```
p.caption {
  color: #777;
  margin-top: 10px;
  padding: 0px 0px 40px 0px;
}
```

Now I'd like to add space before figures included via:

```
knitr::include_graphics(rep("images/knit-logo.png", 3))
```

and before/after all code blocks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figures generated by **bookdown** are wrapped in a `<div>` with the class `figure`, so you can define margins for `div.figure`, e.g.

```
.figure {
  margin-top: 40px;
}
```

You can style other elements in a similar way. If you are not sure about the HTML element name/class, you can right click on an element and inspect it, e.g. in Google Chrome

[image: inspect element]